# Why is my google e-commerce not working?

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-6, e-commerce, ubercart

I have enabled the "Google Analytics" and "Google Analytics for Ubercart" modules. In admin/settings/googleanalytics I set up my Web Property ID. On the Google E-commerce admin page, I enabled "Ecommerce tracking". I then made a purchase on my website, but it is not showing up in the Google e-commerce report.

Things I have tried:
• Enabling the modules: “Google Analytics” and “Google Analytics for Ubercart”
• Changing the role settings to “Add to every role except the selected ones” and leaving the roles blank admin/settings/googleanalytics
• Refreshing the cache: admin/settings/performance
• Installed the Google Analytics debug extension for Chrome

Here's the result of the debug:
Tracking beacon sent!

```
utmwv=5.4.8d&utms=40&utmn=1386010941&utmhn=mysite.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1600x900&utmvp=1585x562&utmsc…373.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~ ga_debug.js:24
Account ID               : UA-myid
Page Title               : Order complete | My Site
Host Name                : mysite.com
Page                     : /cart/checkout/complete
Referring URL            : 0
Hit ID                   : 495430067
Visitor ID               : 173998059
Session Count            : 184
Session Time - First     : Mon Apr 22 2013 09:12:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Session Time - Last      : Thu Mar 13 2014 08:05:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Session Time - Current   : Thu Mar 13 2014 09:41:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Campaign Time            : Mon Apr 22 2013 09:12:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 12.0 r0
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1600x900
Browser Size             : 1585x562
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.8d
Cachebuster              : 1386010941
```

This is some code that is being sent to GA but is not appearing on GA

```
if (typeof(_gat) == "object") { 
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-myid"); 
}
pageTracker._addTrans("44514", "My Site", "96.3", "0", "18.71", "Waterbury", "Connecticut", "United States");
pageTracker._addItem("44514", "TD001", "Custom Frame", "No category", "77.590", "1");
pageTracker._trackTrans();
```

This is some code that is being sent to GA and is appearing on GA

```
if (typeof(_gat) == "object") { 
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-myid"); }
pageTracker._addTrans("44500", "My Site", "29.47", "0", "11.48", "Milwaukee", "Wisconsin", "United States");
pageTracker._addItem("44500", "62028", "Metal Silver 11x14", "Wall", "17.990", "1");
pageTracker._trackTrans();
```

Answer (score 1):

The total (-3.5527136788005E-15) in the `_addTrans` call is suspicious.

You've got a negative total passed to `_addTrans` with positive per-unit price and quantity passed to `_addItem`... looks like your total should be "16.99".

Comment: See my additional code. I put in some debug statements in my code that are logged to watchdog and I added those above.